# Parallel independent waiting for tasks to finish with Task.Wait(millisecondsTimeout)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have application which runs about 30 workers each in it's own thread.
Each worker pass requests from RabbitMQ queue to MS Dynamic Axapta 4.0,
then waiting for response and then return it to RabbitMQ queue.
I wish to implement "request timeout" feature - if AxaptaObject call takes more time than timeout value
then return message "request timeout" and skip request result.
So I make some wrapper for remote request call.

Logic is similar to code below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class TestClass
{
    public static int count = 3;
    public static int timeout = 1000;

    private int id;

    public static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            new TestClass(i);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public TestClass(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        new Thread(Work).Start();
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Task<int> t = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(RemoteRequest);

        bool waitSuccess = t.Wait(timeout);

        s.Stop();
        string result;
        if (waitSuccess)
        {
            result = t.Result.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            result = "timeout";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("TestClass id={0} finished remote request in {1}ms with result={2}", id, s.ElapsedMilliseconds, result);        
    }

    public int RemoteRequest()
    {
        // Dynamics AX 4.0 Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.AxaptaObject.Call()
        Console.WriteLine("TestClass id={0} executing remote request...", id);
        // Do some work
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        return id * 2; // return some result
    }
}
```

Result:

```
TestClass id=0 executing remote request...
TestClass id=1 executing remote request...
TestClass id=0 finished remote request in 516ms with result=0
TestClass id=1 finished remote request in 512ms with result=2
TestClass id=2 executing remote request...
TestClass id=2 finished remote request in 1010ms with result=timeout
```

Can you make me clear about why is in 3-rd task time is about two times longer then Sleep() parameter? (and why message "TestClass id=2 executing remote request..." appears after two previous tasks have finished)

As @BugFinder point out:

> The obvious answer is because only 2 requests could run at one time.

So the question is why only 2 requests could run at one time?

Comment: The obvious answer is because only 2 requests could run at one time, so therefore, you're starting the stopwatch before the task ran, so its timer includes how long it waited before it could run..

Comment: The only explanation of possible reasons I have it's because there is only one processor with two-cores in my computer. Is it right? And what else it may be?

Comment: Are you asking how to cancel or timeout a method call?  If so there are a ton of questions on SO regarding this.  Generally you need to pass in a `CancellationToken` to each method.  You can't just cancel a method gracefully otherwise

Comment: @MickyD, how to cancel method call is in area of my interests also, I have described more widely my problem. But my question was exactly about behaviour of code snippet. And BugFinder make me thought it because of core numbers. But I have set process affinity to 1 with System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr)1; and result is the same.